Can I update the texture and use it on prerecorded vkCmdDraw?
I am trying to render a terminal screen (basically a text matrix) using a text atlas. My plan is loop through every character if it is in the pass the texture coord etc. and call vkCmdDraw , if not then pass the coord of the probable position of the glyph where glyph will be added and add this character to a list, at the end of the drawing i want to recreate the texture and bind it so that the drawing uses updated texture is it possible?
// here a psudo code for better understanding of the situatuion

start_drawing();

for (line : terminal_buffer){

   for (char : line){

     vec2 position =texture_contains(char)? get_position(char) : get_last_position_and_add_to_list(char);
     push_data(position);
     
     draw();
    }

}

if(regen_texture) regen_texture();

end drawing();


Yes, but you would have to complete the texture update before submitting the command list with the draw commands (ie update the texture in a different command list, and make sure it completes before drawing command list runs). Also, it's generally recommended to instead build a list of vertices, update a buffer on the GPU, then run a single draw command.

If I am right then you mean,
1)use a separate cmd buffer to create and transition the image, update and bind the descriptor set
2)submit this command buffer to the queue before the main cmd buffer
But I have some doubts, I heard "CmdDraw save the pipeline state when recording "  if I am not worng that means when drawing it reference the the texture binded to it at that moment, then how does submitting the image after recording working?

If you create a new texture, then it will not work. But Vulkan allows you to update an existing texture. The texture binding is in essence just a pointer to the texture data; the command list doesn't care what pixels are in the texture, it only cares about where it needs to look for those pixels. The separate command list shouldn't create a new texture, it should just perform a texture transfer (specifically vkCmdCopyBufferToImage with specific regions), and some transitions if necessary.

But I may need to recreate the texture to resize the texture if the texture fills up with glyphs and I need to add another one, so what can I do in that case?

Ah, yes, that would pose a challenge. One option could be to just delay rendering of those glyphs for a frame, at a high enough frame rate it will hardly be noticeable. Otherwise this is what sparse texturing is made for. You could also do it with texture arrays, but that would require preallocating the entire array.
